# How fast is space debris travelling?

Tags: debris, velocity

How fast is orbital debris travelling? 
I believe the speeds would vary based on the debris size, so what would be the range of velocities in that case?

Comment: Why do you think it would vary based on the size?

Comment: The speed of debris is the same as anything else in orbit. Size matters not, young Jedi!

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space debris speeds depend on these variables:

- the original orbit of the object that created the debris
- the amount of energy in the event that created the debris (explosion, collision, breakup, accidental release)
- the weight of the debris (given the same amount of input energy, lighter fragments will be launched at higher speeds)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So how do I go about calculating the speed once I know these variables?

Comment: Speeds vary widely. If you start with a satellite collision, you get thousands of fragments going off at various angles and speeds. If you know the orbit of a piece of debris, you can calculate its speed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_speed